# How to detect/identify a serial port programatically in a winform?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, serial-port, delay, detection

I am programming a windows form that will communicate with a microcontroller. 
After the winform is loaded, it should  automatically detect the comport where the microcontroller is connected .

What I am doing is:

```
       - Get the names of the available ports 
       - with a loop through these names :
       - assign the port name to the serial port instance in the form
       - send a command for the detection
       - wait some time 
       - check if some text has been received
       - compare the received message to the identification message 
       - if it is the right one break the loop and return the result, if not 
            continue
```

Below is the code of the function. I am using **thread.sleep** method. But the function is not working and I don't detect the board when it is there.

Can You tell me what is wrong with the function? Is the time delay blocking the reception?  how should I ameliorate it?

This function is excuted at the beginning after loading the form. If I don't find the port, nothing can go forward. On the other side, there are no other threads I have to take into account at that stage of the excution. I thought about the **DatarRceived** Event, but it does not make sense at this stage, it will be activated after the right port has been detected. 
Please let me know what you think

thank you

```
Public Function connect(testport As SerialPort, recognizeText As String, userCommand As String) As Boolean
    Dim intReturnASCII As Integer = 0
    Dim charReturnValue = Chr(intReturnASCII)
    Dim returnMessage As String = ""
    Dim count As Integer = 0

    Dim ports As String() = IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames
    If testport.IsOpen Then
        testport.Close()
    End If
    Try
        For Each newport As String In ports
            testport.PortName = newport

            testport.Open()
            testport.Write(STX & userCommand & ETX)
            Thread.Sleep(200) ' stop the userform and wait for the reception of the response 
            count = testport.BytesToRead
            While count > 0
                intReturnASCII = testport.ReadByte
                returnMessage = returnMessage + Convert.ToChar(intReturnASCII)
                count -= 1
            End While

            testport.Close()
            XMCPort = newport ' Danach instantiate the serial port publicly with port name , is true instantiate 

            If returnMessage.Contains(recognizeText) Then
                Return True
            End If
        Next
        Return False
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try
    count = 0
    returnMessage = ""
End Function
```

Comment: I would probably favor an approach where the form is immediately in a "wait for response" state.  The form loads, and a thread is spawned that probes ports until it finds a live one, then it sets a flag.  Meanwhile, the form waits for this flag.  Whether or not the thread continues depends on your need for further probing.  If not, terminate it.  Either way, you don't lock the UI for this probe.

Comment: That is actually what is happening now, If it does not find the port, I can connect manually. But my goal is to find the port automatically and I can't understand why my function does not work. If it blocks the UI is secondary at this point. Do you have an idea why my polling does not work ? I tested the other side with a manually sent message and it works.thanks